# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, etc etc error

Tags: c#

```
void Update () {
    movement - Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
}
```

What is the issue here? What should i change it to and why?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read [ask], and post a [mcve].  Thank you.

Comment: What do you think this line of code does?  What do you *want* it to do?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I think that example is sufficiently complete for us to see what the problem is.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `-=` instead of just `-`?  In any case you're not assigning the result of the subtraction to anything.

Comment: Explain your code to a [rubber duck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847924/s).

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring the result of the operation. Its result is not assigned to anything, hence this is useless.

Maybe you meant:

```
movement = movement - Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")
```

or

```
movement -= Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")
```

This lines of code produce the same result:
you're updating `movement` with the data coming from `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal").`